# Use PHP to Dynamically Add To .htaccess File?

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, dns, dynamic

What I am trying to do is automate the process of going live with websites.  These websites are all dynamically created using htaccess, so here is an example:

```
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /folder%{REQUEST_URI}?%{QUERY_STRING} [QSA,L]
```

What I do is add a domain alias for *domain.com*, and then point it to my server IP and the htaccess file makes it view what is in the /folder.

It works fine but we are planning to have hundreds of websites and adding that snippet of code to the htaccess manually can get pretty annoying.  Since all I am changing is *domain.com* and the */folder*, is there a way to use PHP to dynamically add to the bottom of the .htaccess file if I create a form and tell it the domain and the folder, it will add it to the bottom of the htaccess file?

That would save so much time.

Thanks so much.

Comment: Yes it is possible, but be aware of the security risks and duplicate entries.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I really do not recommend to allow php to add **ANYTHING** into .htaccess, it's a big security risk.

```
//but here is your code
$f = fopen(".htaccess", "a+");
fwrite($f, "your content");
fclose($f);
```

Comment: @mario: Don't you see that big "I really do not recommend to allow php to add **ANYTHING** into .htaccess, it's a big security risk" ? without code, my answer would be deleted

Comment: @mario: I said "I do not recomment do". If always a big risk and even a small mistake could be phishing paradise

Comment: @mario: Sure you can add whatever you want to add, but not if it's user's input.

Comment: Well, okay. I take the "unsubstantiated" back. It's just vague and not applicable to OPs case then.

Answer (score 6):

Here you go:

```
function writeht($domain, $folder)
{
    $fp = fopen('.htaccess','a+');
    if($fp)
    {
        fwrite($fp,'

RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?'.str_replace('.','\.',$domain).'$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /'.$folder.'%{REQUEST_URI}?%{QUERY_STRING} [QSA,L]');
        fclose($fp);
    }
}

//usage: writeht("domain.biz","yourfolder");
```

Works fine for me with `0644` permissions on `.htaccess` (as php runs under the same user as file's owner)

Comment: Thank you so much.  This worked great.  I know this is a big security risk, what could happen?

Comment: if you found this helpful, you could accept the answer. Until your permissions on `.htaccess` remain 0644 this is not a security risk. (assuming function will be called only by trusted persons)

Comment: OK I accepted it!  One question though, it doesn't work for me at 0644 but it works when I do 0666.  Any idea why?  Is it more of a security risk at 666?

Comment: actually **yes**. by setting 666, you allow everyone to write to your .htaccess file. If it doesn't work at 644 that's because your web server is running under other user (eg. nobody) than file's owner (you) (eg. bob)

Comment: Man, this code will really help me but I don't want to have any security issues.  This will only be available to administrators (very few people) and they will have limited input options.. they will just have an input box for the domain name, and then a drop down for the username which will be the folder.

Comment: by setting the permissions back to 0644, a FTP tunnel may be the solution for you. `$fp = fopen("ftp://user:password@domain.com/.htaccess", 'a+');`. I'm not sure and i have'nt tested this yet. You could try it. Although this is another security risk if someone reads your source code...

Answer (score 2):

Sure. Its just another file as long as the process has permission to write to the file.

Answer (score 1):

A pretty comfortable way is using the PEAR class [File_HtAccess](http://pear.php.net/package/File_HtAccess). But as told before you shouldn't write the file from a PHP-Script that is accessible via web.