# Memory Limit for individual folders or modules

Tags: php, codeigniter, memory-management, hmvc, memory-limit

I'm developing a php application using codeigniter framework with hmvc library, the application will have modules, I want to have different memory limit for each module. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be able to add an `.htaccess` to the root of each module with memory limit config:

```
<IfModule mod_php5.c>
    php_value memory_limit 32M
</IfModule>
```

---

To update the file dynamically, you need to consider that `.htaccess` is a dangerous thing to expose.

I would take great pains to make sure there is NO way to allow user input (even yours because if you can do it someone else can do it) to be written to an `.htaccess` file.

That said, pseudo-code example (caveat emptor):

```
private function _set_mem_limit($limit = 0, $module = '')
{
    //modules
    $available_modules = array(
        'module1' => '/var/www/myApp/modules/module1/',
        'module2' => '/var/www/myApp/modules/module2/',
    );

    //limits
    $available_limits = array(
        '32'    => '32M',
        '64'    => '64M',
        '128'   => '128M',
        '256'   => '256M',
        '512'   => '512M'
    );

    $string = 'php_value memory_limit ';

    // make sure limit is an integer and it is in the available_limits array
    // if so, set string with the selected limit from array. otherwise, exit
    if(gettype($limit) === 'integer' and in_array($limit, $available_limits))
    {
        $string .= $available_limits[$limit];
    }
    else
    {
        die('Problem setting mem limit.');
    }

    // make sure incoming module variable is only alphanumeric and exists in
    // available_modules array. if so, write the limit to the file. otherwise, exit
    if(ctype_alpha($module) and in_array($module, $available_modules))
    {
        $path = $available_modules[$module].'.htaccess';
        $f = fopen($path, 'w');
        fwrite($f, $string);
        fclose($f);

    }
    else
    {
        die('Problem setting path for mem limit.');
    }
}
```

Even though this may work, I wouldn't trust it.

Comment: i love the method which you have mentioned, but leads me to wondering if im able to dynamically modify the .htaccess files with php

Comment: I wouldn't - it's a potential security risk: http://stackoverflow.com/q/6358330/183254 Although there are probably ways to do it securely, it wouldn't be trivial.

Comment: what im trying to achieve here is "dynamically setting the memory limit for each module" any clue?

Comment: Why would you want to do that? Why not set a static limit? What will change that would make you want to change the limit? Number of users? Time of day? It's doable (not easily), but figure out first if you really need it.

Comment: modules will be developed by 3rd party, and they will be executed on my platform, i will need to allow them to buy extra memory for their modules, when they do the application will increase their memory limit

Comment: wow that's exactly what i'm looking for, ill go read more about security risks which you're referring to. Thanks!!!